# How to construct the .map() observable to change data returned from http.get()

Tags: angular, dictionary, observable, http-get

I'm trying to map the results returned from a fake endpoint that contains an array of user objects with properties like id. But I can't figure out what to put into the map operator to make it work, for example, I want to add 10 to all the IDs. Here's my service's code:

```
getUsers(): Observable<IUsers[]> {
    return this._http.get<IUsers[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .map((users: IUsers[]) => users.find(x => (x.id + 10)))
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

inside `.find()`, it returns `'number' not assignable to type 'boolean'`. How should I construct this the arrow function in my `.map()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace your `find` by a `map`. `Find` returns the value for which your evaluation is `true`. `(x.id + 10)` isn't. That is why you get that error.

Comment: So I should use `map` within a `map`? EDIT: it worked!

Comment: This would make a new array with objects that has transformed`id` property, how would I retain the rest of the properties inside the object other than `id`?

Comment: @midnightnoir [The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on Array.map should help. You'll probably want to use something like `users.map(user => { user.id = user.id + 10; return user })`

Comment: is that the same as map operator for the observable?